# Unable to update cart total after shipping option selected

Tags: cart, totals, ce-1.9.2.0

I just updated Magento to 1.9.2 and while testing, I noticed that on the cart page, the `Update Total` button is always disabled even after selecting a shipping option. I'm not sure if I had this same problem before updating.

I don't see any console/JS errors or any errors in the logs. Anyone else experience this/Have any advice on how to debug? I've disabled all extensions, cleared all the cache and still have same problem.

[image]

Comment: Someone in IRc said, that the changes in `base/default/.../cart.phtml` are not transfered to rwd theme, not sure wether you are using or even if this is right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Fabian Blechschmidt for the tip that let me to a fix.

I'm using a theme based on the rwd theme.

I copied over the changes in the file `/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml`

to

`/app/design/frontend/{{my_themes}}/{{my_theme}}/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml`

There was some changes to the forms and also the button html.